# IIS7 Application Pool Setup ApplicationPoolIdentity, NetworkService, or Custom Account

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express, applicationpoolidentity

I inherited an application that has connections to 2 SQL Servers (Data Storage) and a SQLExpress DB (Membership Login).  It was never successfully deployed so my task is to deploy to IIS 7.5 on Server 2008 R2.

Based on what I have read I need to use ApplicaitonPoolIdentity when connecting to SQL Server, and NetworkService when connecting to SQLExpress.  Since I need to use one or the other I decided to use my network account as a test under Custom Account.  It worked as expected.  However a few hours later the Membership login stopped working.  The error pointed me to delete the files in the user profile for SQLExpress and suggested that I change the AppPool to NetworkService.  However on NetworkService I am unable to connect to the SQL Server.  I left it as the Custom Account thinking it was just a fluke.  A few hours later I was required to delete the files in the user profile for SQLExpress again.

I have verified that all my connection strings are correct.  Has anyone seen a setup like this before?  If so, I would appreciate any suggestions on how to setup proceed.

Thanks,
TJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOR ANYONE ELSE WITH THIS ISSUE: In the end I just moved the membership from SQLExpress to SQL Server. I was able to use both ApplicaitonPoolIdentity and Custom Account at that point. To me this seemed like the better path anyways. If you want to make sure SQL works with membership read [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx)